# return count of all column entries containing "keyword"

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table containing many different columns regarding information on employees (I work at something like a temp agency.) So, for example, one query I have gives me a count of jobs grouped by the employees' locations:

```
SELECT job_location, COUNT( job_title ) 
FROM registration
GROUP BY job_location
```

I'd like to take this a step further, if possible. I'd like to be able to count the number of jobs with a certain keyword. So, for example, if the job_location column has entries like "XYZ town", "New XYZ", "XYZ city", I'd like to count the number of entries for "XYZ" (the keyword in this case), regardless of the other words in the field.

Is this even possible? From what I understand, it's pretty difficult. I really appreciate any suggestions. Cheers!

EDIT: Maybe it will help if I tell you why I want to do this. Basically I want the result to tell me how many jobs are in ALL entries containing XYZ, in ALL entries containing ABC, etc for many different keywords (picture a two columned table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  job_location, COUNT(*)
FROM    registration
WHERE   job_location LIKE '%XYZ%'
GROUP   BY job_location
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this - it's very very close to what I need. This does return all the instances of XYZ, but it splits them up. For example, it tells me that there are 2 instances of "XZY city" and 3 instances of "New XYZ." I'd like to get a TOTAL count of all XZY entries, if possible...

Comment: @nv39 sorry I must have missed this part. Try again with my modified query

Comment: thanks again, but this returns something very similar to your OP... I added an edit to the end of my post, does that help explain it?

Comment: Just remove the last line that contains the `group by` and the first element of the selection(leave only the `COUNT(*)`)

Comment: Woohoo! That's great - thank you x a million. JW - do you know how I could extend this query so that I could count several different keywords at once (XYZ, ABC, DEF, etc.) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @nv39 you will have to extend the regex passed to like. I suggest you take a look at LIKE keyword documentation.